# TYPO3 Neos : How to translate labels from YAML in Back-End?

Tags: internationalization, neoscms

TYPO3 Neos configuration yaml files contains `label` attributes, where the translation is hardcoded. If there a system to use external dictionary system, to make labels multi-language compatible ?

Answer (score 1):

As already answered on Twitter those labels will be translateable via Xliff files and the crowdin platform from version 2.0. Using an older version means the only way is to translate them in the source if you really need that.

Comment: Thanks ! Just a question : when version 2.0 will be available ? Didn't found it on the official Roadmap.

Comment: We plan to release the beta this week and final in roughly 4 weeks.

Comment: Thank You, Christian ! So we will wait for 2.0 instead to begin to hack 1.2 :)